# How to force users to select from autocomplete list php and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an autocomplete function that works and the data is selected and displayed. The data for autocomplete values are contained in a .js file.

I am battling with two issues:

1. How can I prevent that users select values not contained in the data file.? EG they type in a value, which is not in the datafile ... I don't want them to be able to submit their own data. An error message or error placeholder would be awesome.
2. When the user type in value and the autocomplete detects a similar value and display the autocomplete, you can only select the value by key down or mouse click. How do I enable `tab` to select the value?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete-ajax" style=" background: transparent;" required placeholder="Type country name and select from list"/>
```

Data File:

```
var countries = {
"0": "South Africa",
"1": "Australia",
"2": "Brazil",
"3": "United States",
"4": "Zimbabwe"
}
```

Autocomplete Function:

```
/*jslint  browser: true, white: true, plusplus: true */
/*global $, countries */

$(function () {


var countriesArray = $.map(countries, function (value, key) { return { value: value, data: key }; });

// Setup jQuery ajax mock:
$.mockjax({
    url: '*',
    responseTime: 2000,
    response: function (settings) {
        var query = settings.data.query,
            queryLowerCase = query.toLowerCase(),
            re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi'),
            suggestions = $.grep(countriesArray, function (country) {
                 // return country.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0;
                return re.test(country.value);
            }),
            response = {
                query: query,
                suggestions: suggestions
            };

        this.responseText = JSON.stringify(response);
    }
});

// Initialize ajax autocomplete:
$('#autocomplete-ajax').autocomplete({
    // serviceUrl: '/autosuggest/service/url',
    lookup: countriesArray,
    lookupFilter: function(suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
        var re = new RegExp('\\b' +      $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
            return re.test(suggestion.value);
        },
        onHint: function (hint) {
            $('#autocomplete-ajax-x').val(hint);
        },
    });
});
```

I have searched similar questions on Stackoverflow but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate the posted field against the array you're expecting. In psuedo-code

```
function check_post($posted_output) {
    $valid_outputs_array = array("val1", "val2");

    if (in_array($poste_output, $valid_outputs_array)) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

This should be done in both Clientside/js for UX reasons and Serverside/PHP for security reasons.

There are also js libraries out there which do "force" the output but I don't have a recommendation offhand, I'd "roll my own" in this instance anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua. I am not a full time programmer, but I love to built my own projects. Would you mind elaborating on where I need to insert your code?

Comment: The code as written is for the serverside end. So it would be put just before your processing and you'd either process it if true or "bounce" it back if false.

For the JS you'll need to convert it to JS and put it as a custom validation rule in whatever JS validator you're using.